# Recover unsaved file from sublime Text 3 window 8

Tags: file, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I accidentally closed the unsaved tab in Sublime Text3 and have lost my file, wanted to know if there is any way to recover it ?
As suggested in many post tried finding in "AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Local\Session.sublime_session". Don't how it can recover the files

Comment: Did you actually *look* at the `Session.sublime_session` file to see if it contains the contents of the file you closed? You should also look in `Auto Save Session.sublime_session` as well. If it's not in either file, you're out of luck. There's a reason an extra dialog box appears when you try to close an unsaved file, asking you if you **really** want to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do this with *ix operating systems, including Windows Subsystem for Linux. Using Windows GUI is similar but more complicated to explain in a reproducible manner.

If you've closed the tab, it will probably not be in `Session.sublime_session` (try it still). It would rather be in `Backup Auto Save Session.sublime_session` if you try to recover it immediately. On Linux it is in Sublime's Local in .config, e.g. under `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Local`.

In that file you could try looking for part of the text you've had, e.g. with `cat ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/Backup\ Auto\ Save\ Session.sublime_session | grep "The text I remember"`. If you're lucky, you would find a `\n`-separated document.

If you want this expanded, you can do this with `awk`, e.g. `cat ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/Backup\ Auto\ Save\ Session.sublime_session | grep "The text I remember" | awk  '{gsub("\\\\n","\n")};1'`.